# MVC4 enum and radio button list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have seen a few threads on this but none seem to apply to MVC4 because the RadioButtonFor html extension method/helper does not exist.

Say I have an enum list - i.e Airlines:

```
public enum Airlines
{
   Unknown = 0,
   BritishAirways = 1,
   VirginAtlantic = 2,
   AirFrance = 3
}
```

How can I bind this to a Radio button list on my view and be able to retrieve the selected item?
What about being able to say "select one item" if there is no selection made?

Answer (score 45):

You can create a custom Editor Template for the enum `Airlines` that will render a radio button list.  In your Model you will have a property of type `Airlines` and tag this property with the `Required` attribute and set `ErrorMessage = "select one item"`.  Don't forget to include the jQuery validation for client side validation if you want it, usually just have to add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` on your Layout or View.  If you don't use the jQuery validation you will need to make the property nullable on the model because enums are just set to the first value by default so MVC will not see it as invalid.  Remember if you change the property to nullable you will also need to change the Model type of your Editor Template to nullable as well.

**UPDATE**

To enable the Editor Template to render a radio button list for any enum, change the template to the following:

```
@model Enum
@foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()))
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m, value)
    @Html.Label(value.ToString())
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

The Editor Template, *Airlines.cshtml*, in the *Views\Shared\EditorTemplates* directory:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.Airlines
@foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MvcTest.Models.Airlines)))
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m, value)
    @Html.Label(value.ToString())
}
```

The Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "select one item")]
    public Airlines Airline { get; set; }
}
```

The action methods:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new TestModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The view:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Airline)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and get back to you soon. What should I do if I don't want a certain enum to be shown in the list? Lets say all enums I am dealing with will have "Unknown". how can I make sure that it does not get rendered but also making sure that a value is selected in the list?

Comment: OK trying this does not quite work for me. I don't get the radio button list but instead just a textbox. how can I make a partial view perhaps and give it the enum and have that partial view take the enum and generically spit out the radio buttons for each item in the enums but also having the postback/submit bind the selected value to the view model?

Comment: If you want to keep a certain value out of the list simply place an `if` statement in the loop and check for it.  Creating a partial view instead of an editor template should be fairly easy, the difference is just semantics really because editor templates are partial views.  Simply create a partial view in whatever *view\controller* directory you want, though putting it in the shared directory may make more sense, then copy the code from the editor template into it.  Than use `@Html.Partial("partialViewName", model)` and pass the enum from your main view model in as the model.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting a textbox instead of the radio button list.  The code I posted worked for me when I ran it locally.  Try checking your code and make sure it exactly matches what I posted.

Comment: also i get text box, how would the editorfor know that it should use that editortemplate(one with @model Enum)?

Comment: for the general case, you need to pass in the name of the template - for example: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeEnum, "EnumRadioButtonList")

Comment: @Cybercop - what GWTF mentioned is accurate, but you could also name your Editor Template the same name as your property and MVC will "know" to grab the editor template by way of naming convention.

Answer (score 33):

I suggest a similar approach to the other answers, but with the following editor template; *EnumRadioButtonList.cshtml*, in the *Views\Shared\EditorTemplates* directory:

```
@model Enum
@foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()))
{
    var id = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(string.Format(
        "{0}_{1}_{2}", ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, Model.GetType(), value));
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButton(string.Empty, value, value.Equals(Model), new { id })
        @Html.Label(value.ToString(), new { @for = id })
    </div>
}
```

The HTML `id` of each radio button needs to be unique. Therefore the above code prefixes the `id` with the bound property's name by means of using `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`. This ensures unique `id`s if the model contained multiple properties that used this enum, and if this editor template was used for each of them.

The accompanying `label` for each radio button will have its `for` attribute correctly set. *This means that the user can select a radio button by clicking the label text, a much bigger and better click target than just the radio button itself.*

For MVC model binding, the radio buttons will all have their HTML `name` property value set to that of the property that was specified in the `EditorFor` call (`Airline` in this scenario).

To use it:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Airline, "EnumRadioButtonList")
```

Comment: This solution works great for Edit page. However, in Create page where there's no selected item yet for the enum radio button, I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Any work around for this problem?

Comment: Thanks @RichardEverett. I instantiated the model object then pass it to the view and it works now.

Answer (score 19):

What do you mean by RadioButtonFor doesn't exist?  I use MVC4 and use that in my code.  For a list you can set multiple to the same name

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Airlines, Airlines.Unknown)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Airlines, Airlines.BritishAirways)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Airlines, Airlines.VirginAtlantic)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Airlines, Airlines.AirFrance)
```

these will be tied to the model so on postback you will see Airlines set to the selected item and when loading the page the matching radio button will be selected.

Comment: I think Ahmed meant that `RadioButtonFor` did not exist *prior* to MVC4 and that the examples he had found did not use the helper method.

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  Generally with a list like this I just have 1 label at the top saying select the best...

Comment: `RadioButtonFor` renders an HTML `input` element with `type="radio"`. Typically you'd also have an HTML `label` next to each one, with a `for` attribute whose value matches the id of the accompanying radio button.

Comment: should be able to just do @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Airlines) in this example.

Comment: I've added an answer with the approach I would propose.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to combine some of the approaches from other answers with some added features:

*EnumRadioButtonList.cshtml*

```
@model Enum
@foreach (var item in EnumHelper.GetSelectList(Model.GetType()))
{
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButton(string.Empty, item.Value, Model.Equals(Enum.Parse(Model.GetType(), item.Value)))
            @item.Text
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

This uses `EnumHelper.GetSelectList()` as a sort of hack so that you can use display attributes with your enum members:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    First,
    [Display(Name = "Second Member")]
    Second,
    Third
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TestEnumProperty, "EnumRadioButtonList")
```

Yields:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XSjt.png)

I'm also using the Bootstrap radio button styles with a separate helper for the inline version:

*EnumRadioButtonListInline.cshtml*

```
@model Enum
@foreach (var item in EnumHelper.GetSelectList(Model.GetType()))
{
    <label class="radio-inline">
        @Html.RadioButton(string.Empty, item.Value, Model.Equals(Enum.Parse(Model.GetType(), item.Value)))
        @item.Text
    </label>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I improved the highest rated answer by [asymptoticfault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011697/asymptoticfault) a bit to reflect selected values too. 
Save this as EnumRadioButton.cshtml to your shared views EditorTemplates folder:

```cs
@model Enum
@foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()))
{
    if (Equals(Model, value))
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m, value, new {@checked = "checked"})
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m, value)
    }

    @Html.Label(value.ToString())
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(item => Model.MyEnumType, "EnumRadioButton")
```