# how to use radiobuttonlist in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to create a simple radio button list selection to choose from the following values:

- Agree
- Disagree
- Not sure

How would we add it in the following razor view? Is it better to create an enum of these values in the `QuestionModel` and use `foreach` to bind with html helper.

Any example or ideas?

```html
@model Survey.Models.Question

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new { QuestionId = Model.QuestionId }))
{
    <h2>Survey</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please Choose</legend>
        <p>
            Question ID:
            @Model.QuestionId
        </p>
        <p>
            Description:
            @Model.Description
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton" />
    </fieldset>

}
```

Answer (score 15):

Using the ASP.NET Html Helpers, there are three various methods you can use for each of the different helpers supplied for radio buttons.

**Method 1**

A simple way to make a radio button list:

```
<div>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButton("Answer", "Agree")
        Agree
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButton("Answer", "Disagree")
        Disagree
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButton("Answer", "Not Sure")
        Not Sure
    </label>
</div>
```

**Method 2**

The above code will post the checked value with a name of "Answer" to the server when you click Submit. If you would like to make this strongly typed, as you did with Model.QuestionId and Model.Description, you could add a Answer property to your model and do the following:

```
<div>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer, "Agree")
        Agree
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer, "Disagree")
        Disagree
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer, "Not Sure")
        Not Sure
    </label>
</div>
```

**Method 3**

Finally, if you would like to get fancy, you can use an enum. Place the following in your controller:

```
public enum AnswerType {
    Agree,
    Disagree,
    NotSure
}
```

Next, add the property to your model:

```
public AnswerType AnswerType { get; set; }
```

And then add the following to your view:

```
@Html.RadioButtonForEnum(m => m.AnswerType)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is also another good question about using radio button lists and ASP.NET helpers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542060/mvc4-enum-and-radio-button-list

Comment: @Malik, did you find any of these answers helpful? Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

this will work
Radio button for model

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
   foreach (var department in Model.Departments)
    {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id) @department.Name
     }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel you could have a public int SelectedRating. You could make it a string and change the values from 114... to string values as well.

```
<div class="radio">
   <label>
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedRating, 114)
      <span>Not Sure</span>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
   <label>
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedRating, 115)
     <span>Agree</span>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
   <label>
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedRating, 116)
     <span>Don't Agree</span>
   </label>
</div>
```