# How to use more than one controller with radiobutton in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am starting with MVC4 and created first project.
I have one model "*People*", one model "*CivilStatus*" and another one that connect both "*PeopleCivilStatus*".
How can I insert new People having a radiobutton to select the CivilStatus?
I want to save a history of People Civil Status.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you provide us with the code you have tried so far

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542060/mvc4-enum-and-radio-button-list) on radiobuttons for an enum

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is easily done using the EditorFor. Here is a sample :

**Classes**

```
public class People
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class CivilStatus
{
    public bool Married { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleCivilStatus
{
    public People Person { get; set; }
    public CivilStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PeopleCivilStatus model)
    {
        //Dostuff
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.PeopleCivilStatus
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Person)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Status)
    <input type = "submit"/>
}
```