# ASP.NET Accessing dropdown values outside of dropdowns?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I am still new to ASP.NET, so please forgive me if the answer to this is obvious.

Our current project has EnumDropDownLists displaying the information of a model member:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.PeoplePerHousehold, "Make a selection", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ep-variable"})
```

The code above shows a dropdown set to "Make a selection" by default, with 's ranging from "1" through "5+".

What I am attempting to do is display these values not as a dropdown, but a series of radio buttons (for every , there is a radio buttons).

I am attempting to use a foreach loop to create the repeating HTML code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PeoplePerHousehold) // Error is here
{
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" data-toggle="radio" name="radPeople" value="none" checked />
        <strong class="radio-circle">
            @item
        </strong>
    </label>
}
```

...but Visual Studio throws an error stating:

> 'lambda expression' does not contain a public definition for 'Get Enumerator'.

I have looked this error up and many approaches to it, but none of them fixed my problem.

The code for the model being used ( @model EnergyWeb.Models.EnergyProfileViewModel ) is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using EnergyWeb.DAL;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EnergyWeb.Models
{
    public class EnergyProfileViewModel
    {
        public string Postcode { get; private set; }
        [Display(Name = "Your suburb")]
        public string SuburbName { get; private set; }
        public virtual Suburb Suburb { get; set; }
        public int SuburbId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "People?")]
        public PeoplePerHousehold? PeoplePerHousehold { get; set;}

        public int PeopleNumSelected { get; set; }

        etc...
```

I would really appreciate any and all help.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You can only loop through collection. and you are trying to loop into single object that is not possible

Comment: I've also tried:

foreach (var item in Model)

and 

foreach (var item in Model => Model.People)

Which didn't work either...

Comment: You didn't getting point. as i said you can only loop into collection of object but you trying to loop in single object. Model is single object not collection so you will get error.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of using @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(), I am assuming that PeoplePerHousehold is a type of Enum.

As @manish stated in comment, you can not foreach a non collection object, and Enum is not a collection, hence you can not foreach it.

if you want to produce Radio button base on enum, have a look at this answer (article):

[MVC4 enum and radio button list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542060/mvc4-enum-and-radio-button-list)

http://romikoderbynew.com/2012/02/23/asp-net-mvc-rendering-enum-dropdownlists-radio-buttons-and-listboxes/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404022/MVC-Enum-RadioButtonList-Helper

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'm not sure if this will apply much outside of my situation, or how good of a solution it is, but to solve my problem I did the following:

I viewed the source of the original, dropdown version to see the HTML being generated was this:

```
<select class="form-control ep-variable" id="idPeoplePerHousehold" name="PeoplePerHousehold">
<option selected="selected" value="">Make a selection</option>
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">4</option>
<option value="4">5</option>
<option value="5">6</option>
<option value="6">7+</option>
</select>
```

So, to convert that to radio buttons I did:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PeoplePerHousehold, 0, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ep-variable" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PeoplePerHousehold, 1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ep-variable" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PeoplePerHousehold, 2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ep-variable" })
```

Etc. for each value.

After that, all that was left was to change the jQuery script to get radio button values instead of dropdown values:

```
'peoplePerHousehold':   $("[name='PeoplePerHousehold']:checked").val(),
```

And it worked! Thank you all for your help!

The one thing I'm still unsure about is how the dropdown knew to do exactly that many options...