# Enum RadioButtonFor Editor Template set value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542060/mvc4-enum-and-radio-button-list) question, I implemented a RadioButtonFor Editor Template. I works great but currently you cannot pass the value you want selected.

```
EnumRadioButtonList.cshtml (Editor Template):
@model Enum

    @foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()))
    {
        if ((int)value > 0)
        { 
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m, (int)value)  
            @Html.Label(value.ToString())
        }
    }
```

I call it from View with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.QuestionResponse, "EnumRadioButtonList")
```

How do I pass the value QuestionResponse (enum) so that the radio button is selected?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom html helper which will give 2-way binding

```
namespace YourAssembly.Html
{
  public static class EnumHelpers
  {
    public static MvcHtmlString EnumRadioButtonListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
      ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
      string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
      if (!metaData.ModelType.IsEnum)
      {
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The property {0} is not an enum", name));
      }
      string[] names = Enum.GetNames(metaData.ModelType);
      StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
      foreach(string value in names)
      {
        string id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", name, value);
        html.Append("<div>");
        html.Append(helper.RadioButtonFor(expression, value, new { id = id }));
        html.Append(helper.Label(id, value));
        html.Append("</div>");
      }
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

add a reference to the `<namespaces>` section of web.config

```
<add namespace="YourAssembly.Html "/>
```

and use it as

```
@Html.EnumRadioButtonListFor(m => m.QuestionResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change like this in your view

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox" class="checkBoxId" value="@Model.checkbox"/>
```

and submit your form

Comment: That wouldn't work for me because I don't want to manage the ids. This is part of a list so there is more than one.

Comment: you can create a list and put in the input before I tested it and it works foreach (var item in list) {<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox" class="checkBoxId" value="@Model.checkbox"/> }

Comment: One of the benefits of using the Editor Template is that it manages the ids, creating the input tag means I would need to manage the Ids.