# RadioButtonFor not binding with partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, radiobuttonfor

I am having an issue with my RadioButtonFor's binding to my post controller action. See below.

**Main View** - Calling an action to load a partial view and surrounding it with a form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterPlaceInPriorPosition", "Placements", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Action("AdvancedSearch", "Home", new { Area = "Common", advancedSearchModel = Model.AdvancedSearch })
}
```

**AdvancedSearch Partial Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult AdvancedSearch(AdvancedSearch advancedSearchModel)
    {

       return PartialView("_AdvancedSearch", advancedSearchModel);
    }
```

**Partial View** - _AdvancedSearch.cshtml

```
@model AdvancedSearch
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Search, new { @class = "form-control no-max-width" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">

                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyActiveStudents, true, new {Name = "studentTypeRadio"}) <label for="MyActiveStudents">My active students</label>

                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AllActiveStudents, true, new {Name = "studentTypeRadio"}) <label for="AllActiveStudents">All active students</label>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**Posting controller action** -FilterPlaceInPriorPosition

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FilterPlaceInPriorPosition(AdvancedSearch filter)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("PlaceInPriorPosition", filter);
        }
```

**AdvancedSearch.cs class**

```
public class AdvancedSearch
{
    public bool MyActiveStudents { get; set; }
    public bool AllActiveStudents { get; set; }
```

If you look at the image you can see that the textbox text binds over but the two radiobuttons do not.
[debugging results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rYhm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're explicitly changing the name attribute of the radio inputs. The value, then, will be posted back to `studentTypeRadio`, *not* `MyActiveStudents` or `AllActiveStudents`. Since there's nothing on your model that matches that, the value is simply discarded.

Instead you should have something like:

```
public class AdvancedSearch
{
    public bool OnlyMyActiveStudents { get; set; } // default will be `false`
}
```

Then in your partial:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OnlyMyActiveStudents, true, new { id = "MyActiveStudents" })
<label for="MyActiveStudents">My active students</label>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OnlyMyActiveStudents, false, new { id = "AllActiveStudents" })
<label for="AllActiveStudents">All active students</label>
```

Also, FWIW, using a child action here is pointless. If all you want to do is pass an instance to the partial view, you can do that with just `Html.Partial` without all the unnecessary overhead of a child action:

```
@Html.Partial("_AdvancedSearch", Model.AdvancedSearch)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a single name attribute to more than 2 radio buttons? In the future I will have more than what I have listed. For example, I will add additional buttons for more filtering. I need radios that are different property names, but part of the same group.  @Igor

Comment: @Jimmy, I would suggest that you use an enum instead of a bool property. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542060/mvc4-enum-and-radio-button-list

Comment: @Jimmy - a group of radiobuttons with the same name represents several mutually exclusive values of the same property. In the model you only need one property for this. It can be a boolean (if there are only two possible values), an integer, an enumeration, a string.

Comment: Yep. Two radios, use a bool. For more than two, use an enum. Either way, you should only have one property per radio group.